# AngularJS Filter vários campos da tabela

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pessoal possuo uma tabela em que é possível filtrar seus dados utilizando filter, onde passo as informações do filter através de um input:

```
<tr ng-dblclick="openUpdateCadProduto(produto)" ng-doubleclick ng-repeat="produto in listaCadProduto  | limitTo:barLimit | filter:{codigo: filtro}">
                    <td>{{produto.codigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{produto.descricao}}</td>
                    <td>{{produto.preco}}</td>
                    <td>{{produto.tabUnidadeMedidaEntity.sigla}}</td>
                    <td>{{produto.codigoBarras}}</td>
                </tr>
```

porém só estou filtrando pelo código, gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar também pela descrição, pelo preço e pela sigla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `$filter` aceita uma expressão como parâmetros além de um `object`, portanto você pode filtrar da seguinte forma:

```
$filter('filter')(array, 'ABC');
```

Ou no `HTML`:

```
ng-repeat="produto in listaCadProduto  | limitTo:barLimit | filter: filtro"
```

Um exemplo prático no `HTML`:

```js
angular
  .module('appFiltro', []);

angular
  .module('appFiltro')
  .controller('FiltroController', FiltroController);

FiltroController.$inject = [];

function FiltroController() {
  var filtro = this;
  
  _iniciar();
  
  function _iniciar() {
    filtro.produtos = [];
    
    filtro.produtos.push({codigo: 1, descricao: 'banana', preco: 2.00});
    filtro.produtos.push({codigo: 2, descricao: 'maçã', preco: 4.00});
    filtro.produtos.push({codigo: 3, descricao: 'tomate', preco: 10.00});
  }
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.5/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appFiltro">
  <div ng-controller="FiltroController as filtro">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filtro.busca"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="produto in filtro.produtos | filter: filtro.busca">
          <td>{{produto.codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{produto.descricao}}</td>
          <td>{{produto.preco}}</td>
          <td>{{produto.preco | currency:"R$ "}}<td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
>
> Selects a subset of items from `array` and returns it as a new `array`.

Em tradução livre:

> Seleciona um subgrupo de itens do `array` e retorna o resultado em um novo `array`.

Comment: No caso então, no Html eu não conseguiria utilizar apenas um campo de filtro para filtrar diferentes campos da tabela? Eu já teria que fazer este filtro no próprio controller do angular?

Comment: @Brayan coloquei um exemplo prático baseado levemente na sua pergunta

Comment: Muito obrigado, solucionou todas as minhas duvidas :D

Comment: @Brayan quer que coloque um exemplo no `controller`?

Comment: Acho que assim já esta ótimo, obrigado :D